# Get JSON data/report from jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am creating an editable tester. I am running jasmine tests and I would like to get the result (JSON data from tests) of tests and represent it on my web page.

Is it possible, and if how?

I do not want to save it somewhere, and then read it. I want that tests return a response, that tells me what happened with tests.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about *jasmine reporters*. There are so many of them now, for instance:

- [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters)
- [`karma-jasmine-html-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter)
- [`jasmine-jsreporter`](https://github.com/detro/jasmine-jsreporter)
- [`jasmine-json-test-reporter`](https://github.com/DrewML/jasmine-json-test-reporter)

Comment: all of this reporters write report to a file, I do not want that. I want that test returns to me the status of all tests.

Comment: @MatjažJurečič then, please state this in the question beforehand.